# How to access data from calling object in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dialog, showdialog

I have a Window-Form 'caller' in vb.net containing a datagridview with a small overview table of certain objects, each with its own ID in the first column. Now, if a row is double clicked, i want to show a dialog 'edit', where one can edit many details of that row which i do not want in the overview table.

My approach is as follows: In the caller form i wrote this to call 'edit':

```
Private Sub dgdata_dbclick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dg_data.CellMouseDoubleClick
        Dim f_edit As New edit
        f_edit.ShowDialog(Me)
End Sub
```

That works fine.

However, in the called Form "edit" i need to check, which ID was selected and load this data from the database to edit it. I can access some data from the calling form 'caller' using e.g.

```
MsgBox(CType(Me.Owner, caller).Text)
```

to show the window title of 'caller'. However, i want to extract the currently selected ID in the datagridview or at least some variabhle containing it. In the caller form, this could be easily done by evaluating

```
dg_data.Item(0, selectedRow).Value.ToString
```

but i cannot access any relevant information in 'caller'. I have a public class with some global variables there but i cannot access them as well.

Probably my strategy to solve this problem is not the most clever approach? Basically, i want to open a very detailed edit window when someone clicks on a line in an overviewtable but simultaniously blocking the rest of the application as long as the edit window is open.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to pass the data to the second form. When you create an instance of the second form (my class is called `Form2`, yours is called `edit`) with the `New` keyword the `Sub New` is called on `Form2`.

```
Private Sub OpenEditDialog()
    Dim f_edit As New Form2(32) '32 is the number you retrieve from your DataGridView
    f_edit.ShowDialog(Me)
    f_edit.Dispose()
End Sub
```

You pass the ID to `Form2` and set a variable at Form level. You can then use the variable anywhere in `Form2`.

```
Public Class Form2

    Private ID As Long

    Public Sub New(SelectedID As Long)
        InitializeComponent()
        ID = SelectedID
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show(ID.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

You need to call `InitializeComponent()` so the controls will show up.

Comment: Hmm, when i add InitializeComponent() my edit form just hangs and does nothing. Without the line, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

How do you usually get data into objects? You set a property or pass an argument to a method or constructor? Why should this be any different? Decide which you want to use and then write that code in your form. If it's required data, I would suggest a constructor. Just write this code in your form:

```
Public Sub New
```

and hit *Enter*. That will generate a little extra code automatically. You can then add a field to store the value, a parameter to the constructor and then assign the parameter to the field inside.

Comment: Thank you very much for thelling me helpful keywords and the hints. Hopefully my solutions is of acceptable style...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing me to the correct route.
I solved it like this (which works fine and which is hopefully acceptable):

In the calling form:

```
Private Sub dgdata_dbclick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dg_data.CellMouseDoubleClick
    Dim selectedRow As Integer = dg_data.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Dim f_edit As New edit
    f_edit.edit(dg_data.Item(0, selectedRow).Value.ToString)
    f_edit.ShowDialog(Me)
    f_edit.Dispose()
End Sub
```

In the called form:

```
Public Sub edit(ByVal id As Long) 'Handles MyBase.Load

'Enter commands to prepare your form

End Sub
```

Comment: Not quite. See my answer.